# for loop in templates

Tags: templates, loops, go

I need `for` loop in template.

```
for i := start; i < finish; i++ {
    // do something
}
```

Is it just one way by using `range` with prepared array or how can I add this functional to templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use `range` and an external function. For example ([On play](http://play.golang.org/p/AKN5BByBdT)):

```
func For(start, end int) <-chan int {
    c := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := start; i < end; i++ {
            c <- i
        }
        close(c)
    }()
    return c
}
```

in the template:

```
{{range For 0 10}}
i: {{.}}
{{end}}
```